# Unexpected dplyr::right_join() behavior for expanding POSIXct time series

Tags: r, join, dplyr, time-series

I have a data frame containing some daily data timestamped at midnight on each day and some hourly data timestamped at the beginning of each hour throughout the day. I want to expand the data so it's all hourly, and I'd like to do so within a tidyverse "pipe chain".

My thought was to create a data frame containing the full hourly time series and then `dplyr::right_join()` my data against this time series. I thought this would populate the proper values where there was a match for the daily data (at midnight) and populate `NA` wherever there was no match (any hour except midnight). This seems to work only when the time series in my data is daily only, rather than a mix of daily and hourly values, which was unexpected. Why does the right join not expand the daily time series when it coexists in a data frame along with another hourly time series?

I've generated a minimal example below. My representative data set that I want to expand is named `allData` and contains a mix of daily and hourly datasets from two different time series variables, `Daily TS` and `Hourly TS`.

```
dailyData <- data.frame( 
  DateTime = seq.POSIXt(lubridate::ymd_hms('2019-01-01', truncated=3), 
                        lubridate::ymd_hms('2019-01-07', truncated=3), 
                        by='day'),
  Name = 'Daily TS'
  )

allHours <- data.frame(
  DateTime = seq.POSIXt(lubridate::ymd_hms('2019-01-01', truncated=3), 
                        lubridate::ymd_hms('2019-01-07 23:00:00'), 
                        by='hour')
)

hourlyData <- allHours %>%
  dplyr::mutate( Name = 'Hourly TS' )

allData <- rbind( dailyData, hourlyData )
```

This gives

```
head( allData, n=15 )
              DateTime      Name
1  2019-01-01 00:00:00  Daily TS
2  2019-01-02 00:00:00  Daily TS
3  2019-01-03 00:00:00  Daily TS
4  2019-01-04 00:00:00  Daily TS
5  2019-01-05 00:00:00  Daily TS
6  2019-01-06 00:00:00  Daily TS
7  2019-01-07 00:00:00  Daily TS
8  2019-01-01 00:00:00 Hourly TS
9  2019-01-01 01:00:00 Hourly TS
10 2019-01-01 02:00:00 Hourly TS
11 2019-01-01 03:00:00 Hourly TS
12 2019-01-01 04:00:00 Hourly TS
13 2019-01-01 05:00:00 Hourly TS
14 2019-01-01 06:00:00 Hourly TS
15 2019-01-01 07:00:00 Hourly TS
```

Now, I thought that `dplyr::right_join()` of the full hourly sequence of `POSIXct` values against `allData$DateTime` would have expanded the daily time series, leaving NA values for any hours not explicitly present in the data. I could then use `tidyr::fill()` to fill these in over the day. However, the following code does not behave this way:

```
expanded_BAD <- allData %>%
  dplyr::right_join( allHours, by='DateTime' ) %>%
  tidyr::fill( dplyr::everything(), .direction='down' ) %>%
  dplyr::arrange( Name, DateTime )
```

`expanded_BAD` shows that the daily data hasn't been expanded by the `right_join()`. That is, the hours in `allHours` missing from `allData` were not retained in the result, which I thought was the whole purpose of using a right join. Here's the head of the result:

```
head(expanded_BAD, n=15)
              DateTime      Name
1  2019-01-01 00:00:00  Daily TS
2  2019-01-02 00:00:00  Daily TS
3  2019-01-03 00:00:00  Daily TS
4  2019-01-04 00:00:00  Daily TS
5  2019-01-05 00:00:00  Daily TS
6  2019-01-06 00:00:00  Daily TS
7  2019-01-07 00:00:00  Daily TS
8  2019-01-01 00:00:00 Hourly TS
9  2019-01-01 01:00:00 Hourly TS
10 2019-01-01 02:00:00 Hourly TS
11 2019-01-01 03:00:00 Hourly TS
12 2019-01-01 04:00:00 Hourly TS
13 2019-01-01 05:00:00 Hourly TS
14 2019-01-01 06:00:00 Hourly TS
15 2019-01-01 07:00:00 Hourly TS
```

Interestingly, if we perform the exact same right join on *only* the daily data, we get the desired result:

```
dailyData_expanded_GOOD <- dailyData %>%
  dplyr::right_join( allHours, by='DateTime' ) %>%
  tidyr::fill( dplyr::everything(), .direction='down' )
```

Here's the head:

```
head(dailyData_expanded_GOOD, n=15)
              DateTime    Value
1  2019-01-01 00:00:00 Daily TS
2  2019-01-01 01:00:00 Daily TS
3  2019-01-01 02:00:00 Daily TS
4  2019-01-01 03:00:00 Daily TS
5  2019-01-01 04:00:00 Daily TS
6  2019-01-01 05:00:00 Daily TS
7  2019-01-01 06:00:00 Daily TS
8  2019-01-01 07:00:00 Daily TS
9  2019-01-01 08:00:00 Daily TS
10 2019-01-01 09:00:00 Daily TS
11 2019-01-01 10:00:00 Daily TS
12 2019-01-01 11:00:00 Daily TS
13 2019-01-01 12:00:00 Daily TS
14 2019-01-01 13:00:00 Daily TS
15 2019-01-01 14:00:00 Daily TS
```

Why does the right join do different things on the full data compared to only the daily data?

Comment: Your example shows the `length(setdiff(allHours$Datetime , allData$DateTime))#
[1] 0`

Comment: @akrun that's true because the hourly time series has all those hours already. However the daily time series doesn't. Does the join short-circuit due to this condition being satisfied? I wouldn't expect the `right_join` to do anything to the hourly data but I was expecting it to expand the daily data. Any thoughts on how to expand the data in a tidy way?

Comment: You can check `expand` or `complete`, but, it can run only in a single `by` or else have to split the data and do it separately

Comment: The issue with expand is that it won't work in the edge case where `allData` contains only daily values. I think `expandedData <- dailyData %>%
  right_join( allHours, by='DateTime' ) %>%
  tidyr::fill( everything() ) %>%
  expand( DateTime, Name ) %>%
  dplyr::arrange( Name, DateTime )` may be the cleanest way to handle all the cases where allData may contain *only* hourly data, *both* hourly and daily data, or *only* daily data. For all three of these cases, this code produces the desired expanded hourly dataset.

Comment: If you are expecting constraints on output or if your chosen query expression relies on constraints on input then you need to describe the constraints on input. PS Learn what left/right join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left/right table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of an outer join. PS Smaller example desired output would be nice. PS Please clarify via edits not comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to bind the dataframes together too soon. I believe this gives you what you want:

```r
result <- bind_rows(dailyData_expanded_GOOD, hourlyData)
head(result)
#>              DateTime     Name
#> 1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 Daily TS
#> 2 2019-01-01 01:00:00 Daily TS
#> 3 2019-01-01 02:00:00 Daily TS
#> 4 2019-01-01 03:00:00 Daily TS
#> 5 2019-01-01 04:00:00 Daily TS
#> 6 2019-01-01 05:00:00 Daily TS
```

The reason `right_join()` doesn't work is that allHours matches perfectly the
rows in allData for hourly timeseries. From ?right_join

> return all rows from y, and all columns from x and y. Rows in y with no match in x will have NA values in the new columns. If there are multiple matches between x and y, all combinations of the matches are returned.

You're hoping that rows in x with no match in y will have NA values, but the rows in y do match rows in x already. There are actually multiple matches, one for the daily and one for the hourly, but `right_join()` just returns both without expanding the daily time series rows.

This is different from the situation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784192/r-time-series-padding-with-na?rq=1), where the datetimes to be expanded do not occur in the left hand data frame. Then the strategy of merging would expand your result as expected.

So that explains why a bare `right_join()` doesn't work, but doesn't solve
the problem because you have to manually split up the data, and that would
get old fast if there are varying numbers of time series. There are a couple solutions in comments, and then one additional that I will add below.

## `tidyr::expand()`

```r
expandedData <- allData %>% 
  tidyr::expand( DateTime, Name ) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange( Name, DateTime )
```

This works, but only with both time series present. If there is only
dailyData, then the result is not expanded.

## The kitchen sink

```r
expandedData1 <- allData %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(allHours, by = 'DateTime') %>% 
  tidyr::fill(everything()) %>% 
  tidyr::expand( DateTime, Name) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange( Name, DateTime )
```

As pointed out in the comments, this works for all cases - both types,
only daily data, only hourly data. This solution and the next generate
warnings unless you use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame()`
calls above.

The only issue with this solution is that `fill()` and `right_join()` are
only there to deal with edge cases. I don't know if that is a real problem
or not.

## "Split" in the pipe

The simple solution splits the dataset, and this can be done inside the
pipe in a couple ways.

```r
expandedData2 <- allData %>% 
  tidyr::nest(-Name) %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map(data, ~right_join(., allHours, by = 'DateTime'))) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest()
```

The other way would use `base::split()` and then `purrr::map_dfr()`

Created on 2019-03-24 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Your bind of `allHours` to `dailyData_expanded_GOOD` doesn't quite achieve what I'm after because it's missing the appropriate values in the `Name` column for the hourly data. What I'm actually looking for is satisfied by `rbind( dailyData_expanded_GOOD, hourlyData)`. However, I was trying to find a vectorized and compact way of achieving this without first splitting the data. It looks like `expand` will do the trick, but only in the case where there is both daily and hourly data. If only daily data, I would need to first `right_join` all hours and then expand.